# TextBox is not updating contents

Tags: c#, winforms

Unlike most questions about GUI form elements not updating properly, this one is not about the GUI thread being blocked (at least that I'm aware of).

I have loop that creates and shows a form instance with each iteration. The form's constructor accepts some text that I show in a textbox. The first time through the loop I can see the text, but after the text no longer shows up.

#### Code for the form:

```
public partial class Message : Form
{
    private StreamReader _inputReader= null;
    private string _inputString = @"";

    public Message(StreamReader reader)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _inputReader = reader;
        Load += Message_Load;
    }

    public Message(string input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _inputString = input;
        Load += Message_Load;
    }

    private void Message_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inputReader == null)
        {
            //form was constructed with a string
            textBox.Text = _inputString;
        }
        else
        {
            //form was constructed with a StreamReader
            textBox.Text = _inputReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        textBox.Select(0, 0);
    }
}
```

#### Code for the loop where form is created:

```
string installNoticeFP = @"Test.notice.txt";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(installNoticeFP));
while (!installerExists()) //returns a boolean
{
    Message message = new Message(sr);
    message.ShowDialog();
    message.Dispose();
}
```

I have made sure there is nothing in the `Message.Designer.cs` file that could be overriding the value of `textBox.Text`

What do I need to do to make the text appear in the `TextBox` every time?

Comment: Add the code to the question, don't link pastebin.

Comment: In the very rare cases where it's appropriate to link to source elsewhere rather than adding a minimal but sufficient sample to your question, at least use dropbox or github. I've never heard of Hastebin. Fat chance I'll click through to it.

Comment: @Gusman I chose to not put the code in the question because the class was lengthy (64 lines), and decided to just put other snippet in a hastebin for unity

Comment: @EdPlunkett i thought it was pretty common, thanks for pointing that out. I'll do that in the future

Comment: hastebin is similar to pastebin

Comment: @user6710080 I never would have guessed. Never in a million years. Seriously, though: 64 lines is no big deal, and it's probably not all necessary. Paste the code in the question as text next time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett haha. Also, I elected to put the entire source rather than a snippet because I didn't know where the problem was coming from, just that it was something in either the form class or the snippet that created the form

Comment: Fair enough, but 64 lines is still no big deal, if you really need to provide that much code. Sometimes a question ends up with a couple hundred lines of code. The code blocks on SO sprout vertical scrollbars when they get long. Far better to provide too much code than to be one of these guys who pastes one line and won't even say what method it's in.

Comment: I added the code  (cut down by about a third).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the textbox but with the stream. You are reading the stream to retrieve the string, and the next time you pass the same stream to the form the stream is at the end, so there's nothing to read from it.

Add this before passing the stream to the form:

```
sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

That will make the stream to be at the begin and you will be able to read the data again.

But better, read the stream before the loop into an string and pass that string to the form, it will be more efficient.

Comment: This works, thank you so much! I'll mark it as accepted after the minimum time has passed. Thank you!

Comment: @user6710080 Remember to add the code to the question

Comment: Would you consider it ok to put the class code (64 lines) in a gist and link that?

Comment: @user6710080 Personally I would add the full code, it's not so long to justify the need to go to an external page to read the code. It's a lot easier for any other user who reads this question to understand it if the code is directly on it.

Comment: @user6710080 A lot better :)